# Find all dependents of a particular service with Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, service

Is there a way to get a list of all functions, services, controllers, directives etc. that explicitly declared a dependency on a specific service?

Why do I need it?

Because the service provides data and resources to dependents and should be able to notify those dependents when the corresponding data and/or resources change.

If that is not possible, I am guessing, I should simply add an event to the service and have every dependent register/subscribe to that event explicitly; or is there another way?

Comment: The solution you proposed in your last paragraph is the good one.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, it is not possible.